# pass array to sql insert query php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a sql query to insert data without col names :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (null,1,2,3) ";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {echo  'success!';}else {echo 'failed!';}
```

I want to insert 1,2,3 as array , something like this:

```
$data = [1,2,3];    
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (null,$data) ";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {echo  'success!';}else {echo 'failed!';}
```

I tried php implode function too, but it didn't worked. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `implode()` should have worked, show what you tried.

Comment: But it's generally preferable to use prepared statements with `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`, to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: $data = implode(','  , $data);
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (null,$data) ";

Comment: That should have worked with numbers as in your code snippet. It won't work with strings, since they need quotes around them.

Comment: its for internal use only, so sql injection is not a concern

Comment: SQL injection is always a concern. It's not just for protection against attacks, it also protects against syntax errors.

Comment: For instance, it will handle strings properly.

Comment: It worked! I had mix numeric and string values. Adding quote fixed the issue. Thanks alot!

Comment: Very simply, this is poor practice for numerous reasons, beyond the ones @Barmar related.  You should never write insert code like this, where you only provide values.  You should always enumerate the fields.  For auto increment keys you can omit the column entirely.  Why?  Later someone adds a field to the table (could be a timestamp for example), and now your code is broken.  Also use prepared statements as advised.  [This page](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/insert)  will get you going in no time.  If you have a choice use PDO instead of mysqli.  99% of PHP pros agree.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the table structure that it is going into, but if all you are wanting to solve for is having the $data array split into constituent parts you could do it several ways:

a) implode(), although you already mentioned trying it, should work just fine:

```
$data = [1,2,3];    
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (null,".implode(',',$data).")";
```

b) reference each array index:

```
$data = [1,2,3];    
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (null,{$data[0]},{$data[1]},{$data[2]})";
```

That only works if you have a set amount of values in the array however.

c) loop over the array:

```
$data = [1,2,3];    
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (null"
foreach($data as $value){ $sql .= ",$value"; }
$sql .= ")";
```

Hope that helps, if not please provide more details about the structure of both the data going in and the database table so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: Your last example has an extra `,`. That's why I hate loops like that, fencepost errors are very likely. I always use `implode()`.